# NodeJS Can't Access Variable Inside Callback

Tags: node.js, mongoose, locomotivejs

I believe this is a problem with it being async, but I do not know the solution.

```
    PagesController.buy = function() {

  var table="";
  Selling.find({}, function(err, res) {
    for (var i in res) {
      console.log(res[i].addr);
      table = table + "res[i].addr";
    }
  });
  this.table = table;
  console.log(table);
  this.render();
}
```

My issue is that `this.table=table` is returning undefined if I try access it outside of the function, and I cannot figure out how to display the table on the page.

Comment: How are you trying to access "this.table" outside of the function?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the variable "table" is set inside the function (err, res) { } , and when I try assign it to this.table, the variable "table" is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the Selling.find is asynchronous and likely isn't complete by the time the this.table = table is executed. Try something like the following.

```
PagesController.buy = function() {
  var that = this;
  Selling.find({}, function(err, res) {
    var table = '';
    for (var i in res) {
      console.log(res[i].addr);
      table = table + res[i].addr;
    }

    that.table = table;
    console.log(table);
    that.render();
  });
}
```

That will guarantee that table isn't used until after the results have been fetched and table has been populated.