# Node JS access value outside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, google-distancematrix-api

I have a problem access value outside callback, I have a json like below

```
[ { Latitude: '3.59288601404616',
    Longitude: '98.6827551573515',
    Latitude1: '3.5828173285855724',
    Longitude1: '98.69136337190866',
  },
   { Latitude: '3.65865664490563',
     Longitude: '98.6652326211333',
     Latitude1: '3.5828173285855724',
     Longitude1: '98.69136337190866',
  } ]
```

I have read a lot of web said that its impossible to get value from the callback because we have to wait until the callback finish first then we can have a value and some question in stackoverflow provide some solution but no one is work for me.

What I want to get is to add a new json inside that json that I post above, I want to add Distance json inside so I use [node-google-distance](https://github.com/edwlook/node-google-distance)

What I want is like this

```
[ { Latitude: '3.59288601404616',
    Longitude: '98.6827551573515',
    Latitude1: '3.5828173285855724',
    Longitude1: '98.69136337190866',
    Distance '10127'
  },
   { Latitude: '3.65865664490563',
     Longitude: '98.6652326211333',
     Latitude1: '3.5828173285855724',
     Longitude1: '98.69136337190866',
     Distance: '1836'
  } ]
```

and my code like this

```
models.xxxx.findAll({
    where: {
        UserId: req.params.UserId
    },
    attributes: ['Latitude', 'Longitude', [sequelize.literal('(SELECT Latitude FROM `xxxx` WHERE `id` = ' + req.params.MerchantId + ')'), 'Latitude1'],
        [sequelize.literal('(SELECT Longitude FROM `xxxx` WHERE `id` = ' + req.params.MerchantId + ')'), 'Longitude1']
    ]
}).then(function(lists) {

    var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lists));

    function get_count(item, callback) {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            distance.get({
                    origin: json[i].Latitude1 + ',' + json[i].Longitude1,
                    destination: json[i].Latitude + ',' + json[i].Longitude
                },
                function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        array.push(0);
                    } else {
                        array.push(data.distanceValue);
                    }

                    item.distanceValue = array;
                });
        }
        callback(null, item);
    }
    async.map(json, get_count, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

I use `async.map` because in this web someone post it
[Javascript: return a value to a variable outside of a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852361/javascript-return-a-value-to-a-variable-outside-of-a-callback-function), I spend a lot of time search in stackoverflow but found nothing

[NodeJS Can't Access Variable Inside Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471548/nodejs-cant-access-variable-inside-callback)

[How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

[NodeJS get async return value (callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399725/nodejs-get-async-return-value-callback)

[Site 1](http://oskarhane.com/javascript-external-global-variables-in-async-callbacks/)

[Site 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/waiting-for-a-loop-of-async-functions-to-finish-in-node-js/)

Please give me some hint or some example how to fix this problem

Comment: Several questions/issues: 1. Are `json` and `jsonData` meant to be the same variable? If not, where does `jsonData` come from? 2. Note that `json` refers to something that by definition **isn't** JSON (it's been parsed). 3. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` is both an inefficient and incorrect way to clone an object tree.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `json` and `jsonData` actually same, I just have misplaced copy paste the content, and about `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))` I don't have a problem with that because it still display the result, my problem is I can't add a new json into it

Comment: Again: Once you parse it, it's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you post some example about it ? actually I can't get any value from `var array = [];` when I use console.log the `get_count` give me empty array so I can't test it

Comment: Simple: `var json = '{"foo":"bar"}'; var notJson = JSON.parse(json);`